# c# overload error for generic type

Tags: c#, generics, overloading

I want to use methods overload to get  different result according to different generic types. It does not work. My code show it clearly.

```
static class Helper
{

    public static bool Can(int i)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static bool Can(Object o)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class My<T>
{
    public static bool can = Helper.Can(default(T));
}

Console.WriteLine(Helper.Can(default(int)));//True,it is OK

Console.WriteLine(My<int>.can);//false?? why the overload doesn't work
Console.WriteLine(My<Object>.can);//false
```

Why `My<int>` calls Helper.Can(Object o) rather than Helper.Can(int i)?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work that way.

Overloads are resolved entirely at compile-time; generic type parameters are resolved at runtime.
Since the compiler doesn't know that `T` is `int`, your code will always call `Can(Object)`.

Comment: I wouldn't quite agree with the statement that "generic type parameters are resolved at runtime". If that were the case, the compiler couldn't tell at compile-time that you can't get an int item from a `List<string>`. What *is* considered unresolved at compile-time are occurrences of the generic type parameter within the generic class.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I meant within the generic class.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, it will resolve to Object at compile time, but you can tell it to wait until runtime by using the *dynamic* keyword:

```
class My<T>
{
   public static bool can = CanWithDynamic();

   private static bool CanWithDynamic() {
      dynamic runtimeT = default(T);
      return Helper.Can(runtimeT);
 }
```

So, this will work for what you're trying to do and the right overload will be called. However, as with anything that is resolved at runtime there is a performance cost associated with it. Probably not much of one, but if you call this method frequently it could have an impact.

Answer (score 1):

it is a little bit verbose, but you could achieve what you want by using Reflection:

```
class My<T>
{
    static bool doStuff()
    {
        var rightMehod = typeof(Helper).GetMethods().Where(p =>
            {
                if (!p.Name.Equals("Can"))
                    return false;

                if (!p.ReturnType.Equals(typeof(bool)))
                    return false;

                if (p.GetParameters().Length != 1)
                    return false;

                var par = p.GetParameters().First();
                return par.ParameterType.Equals(typeof(T));
            }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (rightMehod == null)
        {
            return Helper.Can(default(T));
        }
        else
        {
            return (bool)rightMehod.Invoke(null, new object[] { default(T) });
        }
    }

    public static bool can = doStuff();
}
```

This way,

```
My<string>.can == false
My<int>.can == true
My<object>.can == false
```

Of course, with a bit of additional craft (and usage of generic types), you would be able to re-use that snippet extensively for many different situations.

One additional remark: in this example, I have used direct type comparison for your specific example. Note that this will not work properly when dealing with inherited types (and of course, there are some additional ambiguities as well :).